# Can't order ActiveRecord Relation by time in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I got this query and would like to order the results by 'delivery_time':

```
d = Date.today.at_midnight
orders = car.orders.where("finished_at IS NOT NULL AND delivery_time > ?", d).order(delivery_time: :desc)
```

The problem is, the order method doesn't work - it still gets ordered by id! Whatever I put into the order method arguments doesn't seem to work.

This is what my **orders table** partially looks like:

```
  create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "delivery_time"
    t.datetime "finished_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**car.rb:**

```
has_many :orders, -> { order "delivery_time ASC" }
```

**.explain output:**

```
 SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders`  WHERE `orders`.`car_id` = 1 AND (finished_at IS NOT NULL AND delivery_time > '2014-09-09 03:00:00')  ORDER BY delivery_time ASC, `orders`.`delivery_time` DESC
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `.explain` or the SQL being generated?

Comment: Do you have some default_scope in your model?

Comment: Actually it's car.orders - I updated my question, added the car model default scope and the `.explain` output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to override ordering, try using [`reorder`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#reorder) instead of `order`.

```
orders = car.orders.where(
  "finished_at IS NOT NULL AND delivery_time > ?", d
).reorder(delivery_time: :desc)
```